# Open specific URLs in PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I would like to have all of my browser tabs for a given URL prefix automatically open in a PWA window. Is that something that I can do as a consumer of the site, or is it something that the site has to publish?

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is covered by an ongoing [Origin Trial](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/origin-trials/) (i.e., speculative feature that's being experimented with) in Chrome, known as the [Launch Handler API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/launch-handler/).

I would suggest trying out that feature and potentially giving feedback about whether it meets your needs. Developer usage and feedback will help determine if and when that feature ends up shipping by default in Chrome and potentially other browsers, like Edge.

Comment: I will be trying this - just juggling too many things right now.